# How to refer to another bean as a property in annotation-based configuration file

Tags: java, spring

In XML context based bean configuration file, if I want to refer a bean as property, I would use:

```
<bean class="com.example.Example" id="someId">
    <property name="someProp" refer="anotherBean"/>
</bean>
<bean class="com.example.AnotherBean" id="anotherBean">
</bean>
```

So the `Example` bean will use the `anotherBean` as its property

So in the concept of annotation-based configuration java file:

```
@Configuration
class GlobalConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Example createExample(){
        return;
        //here how should I refer to the bean below?
    }

    @Bean
    public AnotherBean createAnotherBean(){
        return new AnotherBean();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is a first solution, where you have both bean definitions in one `@Configuration` class.

```
@Configuration
class GlobalConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Example createExample(){
        final Example example = new Example();
        example.setSomeProp(createAnotherBean());
        return example;
    }

    @Bean
    public AnotherBean createAnotherBean(){
        return new AnotherBean();
    }
}
```

Second possibility is to use autowiring like below:

```
 @Configuration
    class GlobalConfiguration {
        @Bean
        @Autowired
        public Example createExample(AnotherBean anotherBean){
            final Example example = new Example();
            example.setSomeProp(anotherBean);
            return example;
        }

        @Bean
        public AnotherBean createAnotherBean(){
            return new AnotherBean();
        }
    }
```

Third possibility is to split those declarations among two different `@Configuration` classes and use autowiring.

```
@Configuration
class FirstConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public AnotherBean createAnotherBean(){
        return new AnotherBean();
    }
}

@Configuration
class SecondConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private AnotherBean anotherBean;

    @Bean
    public Example createExample(){
        final Example example = new Example();
        example.setSomeProp(anotherBean);
        return example;
    }
 }
```

Comment: You could also add the `@Autowired`annotation (with maybe a `@Qualifier`) in the Example bean class definition if that is possible and skip the setter in the bean instantiation.

Comment: thanks @JeremyGrand, I only checked the second solution you proposed, since it is neat and nice-looking. It works, the second solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
@Configuration 
class GlobalConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Example createExample(@Autowired AnotherBean anotherBean){
        //use another bean
        return new Example(anotherBean);
    }

    @Bean
    public AnotherBean createAnotherBean(){
        return new AnotherBean();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Autowired seems to be redundant here

Comment: nooo.. we don't want 'new AnotherBean( )'. We don't want to create new instances of anotherbean. We want to autowire i.e. use the singleton anotherbean which is in spring bean context.